# unable to send post request using HTMX + Django

Tags: django, htmx

I'm trying to create a CRUD page using django + HTMX and unable to send POST request.
hx-post sends a GET request instead of POST request.

my Role Models is as follows:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I'm creating the form using Cripsy Forms as follows

```
class RoleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Role

      fields = ('name', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields['name'].label = "Role"

        self.helper.add_input(Submit('add_new_Role', 'Add', css_class='role_button'))
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('name'),
            )
        )
```

I'm using the form in my template like this :

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="card col-md-6 ml-auto mr-auto">
    <div class="card-body">
      {% crispy role_form %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="role_list">
  {% include 'role_list.html' %}
</div>


{% endblock %}


{% block javascript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").removeAttr("method");
    $('.role_button').attr("hx-post", '{% url "role_add" %}');
    $('.role_button').attr('hx-target', '#role_list');

  });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

The CDN link is added in the main.html file.

My understanding is that clicking the ADD button should trigger a POST request.
However GET request is initiated, which makes me feel like the HTMX part did not work at all

Comment: The button is submitting the actual HTML form. Most browsers will interpret the first button in a form to be a submit button, even if you don't explicitly set it as such. This makes sense since you're removing the `method` attr from the form, and forms without a `method` attr default to GET.

Comment: Instead of inserting HTMX attributes via js, you can set them directly via FormHelper: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html#helper-attributes-you-can-set

Comment: @Jesse My understanding is that since we have `hx-post` attribute in the button being clicked, it should end up sending a POST request with the form contents. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Marco : the helper attributes is available only for form and input fields. It does not have an option to add attributes to submit button which I'm trying to do here

Comment: You're not wrong, that's what I thought too. The docs sounds like it will grab any nearby form data it can find, but it doesn't say anything about the method. There's also very little documentation around forms for htmx, which makes me wonder if they want you to just use forms like you would normally. So, skip the HTMX bit and just configure the attr on the form itself

Comment: @Jesse adding the attributes on the form will result in the form getting submitted witha page refresh, which will defeat the purpose of HTMX. having the hx-post attribute in submit function should should pick up the form content and POST it on click . HTMX does this without refreshing the page.

Comment: Ah ok I see. In that case you can just disable the form from submitting. `<form onsubmit="function(e){e.preventDefault()}"></form>`

Comment: @Jesse HTMX definitely supports forms, and you don't need to do any custom `preventDefault()` stuff. You just need to place the HTMX attributes on the `form` element itself, instead of trying to place them on the submit button element.

Comment: If you add a `hx-post` attribute to a form, htmx will submit the form when the form's submit event fires. If it's not working, it may be because htmx isn't loaded. You can type `htmx` into browser dev tools console to see if htmx is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this is to add the `hx-post` and `hx-target` attributes to the `form` element, not the `submit` button. This will cause HTMX to intercept the submit event on the form, and submit the entire form as an AJAX request.

See the [Triggering Requests](https://htmx.org/docs/#triggers) documentation:

> By default, AJAX requests are triggered by the "natural" event of an
> element:
>
> - form is triggered on the submit event

Answer (score 1):

As @Mark said in his answer, I would suggest to define form tag on your template and put `htmx` stuff onto that:

```html
<form hx-post={% url 'submit url' %}  <!-- Do not set action and method -->
 ...other htmx attributes>
    {% crispy form %}    
</form>
```

and set your form helper to doesn't render a form tag

```py
self.helper.form_tag = False
```

And by the way, if you've set htmx to send `csrf` automatically, (See [here](https://www.mattlayman.com/blog/2021/how-to-htmx-django/) for more info) It's better to disable `csrf` in your form helper as well

```py
self.helper.disable_csrf = True  # no need, request is sent via htmx
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after a too many trial and errors.
Turns out Django Crispy forms create an input with `type='submit'` to create the submit button

however, hx-post works only if you have a button with `type='submit'` instead of input in order to submit the form

Comment: Your answer seems to have a typo, because you are basically saying that Crispy forms creates an input with the correct submit button, but that it is a problem somehow?

Comment: I don't think it's correct. I'm working with `htmx` in a project and my form have `<input type="submit" />` working completely OK with htmx. Your problems lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark said in his answer
Here my way to type the HTMX code in crispy-forms.

```
            <form class="form-inline" 
            hx-get = "{% url 'myurl' %}"
            hx-target="#myinclude"
            >
                 {{  form|crispy }}
              <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success" 
              >Search</button>
            </form>
```

Typing the code in the <button hx-get....htmx ajax call doesn't work.
If you want to see some code example and tutorial about HTMX Pandas and Crispy working together here my own page to find them
[Htmx django-filter Pandas and Crispy form](https://www.managepy.it/demo/)